# What do the little Egyptian men mean?

Tags: the-pyraplex

I noticed that when I have visitors in my pyramid, they sometimes have little Egyptian men that appear over their heads. This happens mostly when they are looking at my murals. What do those little men mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those little Egyptian men are the mural's "products".  If you tap on the mural, the sub-window details will show Price, and the same icon beside it.  The visitors are essentially buying something the mural has to offer.  What, exactly, I'm not sure.  Artwork, maybe?  Either way, visitor buys little Egyptian men, and you get money.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I didn't understand because I didn't realize the mural sold stuff. That's weird.